# SpringData mapping entities without annotations

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a jar with entities which code I cannot modify or do anything other than use them and I **must** use that jar.

I'm trying to use those entities to persist them in mongodb and I'm using Spring, so I went with SpringData instead of Hibernate (also because I read some things that led me to choose SpringData over Hibernate NoSQL impl). Anyway, I haven't been able to make it work because I haven't find any way to set the properties of a collection on them, like the indexing, uniqueness, compound indexes, etc. Right now I can store it and everything but I'm losing a lot of mongo features by not been able to properly configure my entities.

I've looked for an xml configuration or some other form of mapping that doesn't require modification of the existing code.

So far the only "solutions" I could came up with was

1. Create the collections by inserting some dummy data, delete it and then use WriteConverter's and ReadConverter's for the mapping.
2. Duplicating the exact same entities on my code and add them the respective annotations and then convert them to the ones in the jar, but this would be my last resort.

Any ideas or alternative solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: I would even generalize this question so that what if some one does NOT want to pollute the domain objects with third party annotations like ones from Sprint Data. Jackson has a solution for similar problem with mixins.

Comment: Yeah, I looked for exactly that (not the jackson part) and couldn't find anything. But you are right, I should've been more general about the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate with xml mappings in a orm.xml, it contains all the configuration details required for mapping a class to a relational database table. These details include the primary key of the entity class and the various constraints/ rules to be applied for the primary key.

For more information you can check this link [enter link description here](https://dzone.com/articles/persisting-entity-classes)

This [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/mikaelhg/8c85f3251c0ba5690167) is an example  of how to do it with Spring data

Comment: the second link is a JPA specific format, is there similar thing for each Spring Data module? specifically here for mongoDB?