# Spring Data - hibernate.cfg.xml in different package

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture

I'm new to Spring, and trying to create a hexagonal architecture with spring data

I have a gradle multi-module setup with on package for the domain, one for persistence, and another for configuration, where the DddApplication lives.

When starting it up, I get `Not a managed type: class com.example.ddd.domain.model.Customer`, unless I annotate the class with  javax.persistence.@Entity etc.

However I don't want annotations in the class. I had set up entities in hibernate.cfg.xml and Customer.hbm.xml in the `persistence` package.

I think spring boot isn't using hibernate.cfg.xml from the other package.

Is there any way I can configure Spring Boot to recognise the entities based on the hibernate.cfg.xml in the `persistence` package?

```
package com.example.ddd.configuration

// ...

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.example.ddd.domain.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.ddd.persistence.repository")
class DddApplication {
    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DddApplication::class.java)

    @Bean
    fun loadData(repository: CustomerRepositoryJpa): CommandLineRunner? {
        return CommandLineRunner { args: Array<String?>? ->
//...
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DddApplication>(*args)
}
```

```
package com.example.ddd.persistence.repository

//...

@Repository
interface CustomerRepositoryJpa : JpaRepository<Customer?, Long?> {}
```

```
package com.example.ddd.domain.model

open class Customer private constructor() {
    val id: Long? = null
    lateinit var firstName: String
    lateinit var lastName: String
    override fun toString(): String {
        return String.format("Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']", id,
                firstName, lastName)
    }

    companion object {
        fun new(firstName: String, lastName: String) : Customer {
            val e = Customer()
            e.firstName = firstName
            e.lastName = lastName
            return e
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties and hibernate.cfg.xml are in the resources of the `persistence` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look to this answer and attached code snippets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531971/springdata-mapping-entities-without-annotations#48532255).
The idea is to make spring-data use the orm.xml configuration file where you can define your domain objects JPA specificities.

**Some remarks**

The only thing that bother you here are JPA annotations.
These annotations are a **declarative** way to indicate that your domain objects (entities, value types) can also be considered as JPA entities.

You might comply with DDD, Hexagonal architecture & [**KISS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principles letting them reside in your domain. 
Indeed, they do not create a strong dependency to any technical persistence framework like Hibernate; because they are annotations, and also because only the [jpa spec library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2) is required here, as dependency for your domain. 
Such domain repositories could later be implemented with something else than Hibernate (NoSQL, AWS S3, whatever...), keeping these annotations into your domain.

This is a trade off between code simplicity and hexagonal principle applying, as XML orm file looks harder to maintain compared to annotations. 
However such file would avoid JPA annotations pollution of your domain or the add of an extra JPA entities layer outside the hexagon.

Comment: Turns out the key is to have `META-INF/orm.xml`. If that file is present, then the hibernate xml mappings get read, and I would assume any JPA mappings would too. I agree now that the annotations are probably the most pragmatic solution anyway, especially since most of the documentation and examples use them. The only niggle is that they describe storage-specific concerns inside the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it defining mappings, fields, etc in a XML configuration file ("orm.xml"), instead of putting JPA annotations in entity class. I would not polute the entity with JPA stuff, since JPA is about persistence, it is technology and it should be in an adapter outside the hexagon.